# How to print or display all combination of two string list

Tags: c#, html

Currently I have 2 list.
Ex :

```
List1
A
B
C

List2
a
b
c
d
```

Expecting the output as

```
Col1  Col2
A      a
A      b
A      c
A      d
B      a
B      b
B      c
B      d
C      a
C      b
C      c
C      d
```

How to generate like this?

Currently I have 2 list.
Ex :

```
List
A
B
C

List
a
b
c
d
```

I need the output as

```
Col1  Col2
A      a
A      b
A      c
A      d
B      a
B      b
B      c
B      d
C      a
C      b
C      c
C      d
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This may help you => [How to get multiple combination of items from multiple list in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443418/how-to-get-multiple-combination-of-items-from-multiple-list-in-c-sharp/52443467#52443467)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d"};

            list1.ForEach(res =>
            {
                list2.ForEach(res1 =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(res + "  " + res1);
                });
            });
```

And the output is:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Use simple LINQ to iterate over on both list like

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };


var result = (from x in list1
              from y in list2
              select new
              {
                  Col1 = x,
                  Col2 = y
              }).ToList();


Console.WriteLine("Col1 \t Col2");

result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Col1 + "\t" + x.Col2));

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can find from your question, you can simply do it with two nested loops. but if you want to create a combination list, you can use the following code :

```
IList<string> List1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C"};
IList<string> List2 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d"};
IList<string> combination = List1.SelectMany(g => List2.Select(c => new { Value = g.ToString() + c.ToString() })).Select(a => a.Value).ToList(); 
foreach (var c in combination)
{
     Console.WriteLine(c); 
}
```